# Require explaination for some variables used in bash script

Tags: bash

Simple bash script to generate subnet from ip and netmask which i got after some googling.It as below

```
#!/bin/bash
sub_net()
{
    A=$1
    B=$2
    OFS=$IFS
    IFS="."
    set ${A:-0.0.0.0}
    A1=${1:-0}
    A2=${2:-0}
    A3=${3:-0}
    A4=${4:-0}

    IFS="."
    set ${B:-0.0.0.0}
    B1=${1:-0}
    B2=${2:-0}
    B3=${3:-0}
    B4=${4:-0}

    IFS=$OFS

    C4=$(( B4 & A4 ))
    C3=$(( B3 & A3 ))
    C2=$(( B2 & A2 ))
    C1=$(( B1 & A1 ))

    echo ${C1}.${C2}.${C3}.${C4}
}

sub_net 181.172.0.111 255.255.255.0
```

i know the `IFS` usage it's for field separator but at around line:8 the code`set ${A:-0.0.0.0}` written so what is use of it. For debugging i just comment that line but got following error

```
./script.bash: line 33: 255.255.255.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".255.255.0")
```

Can anyone explain usage of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
set ${A:-0.0.0.0}
```

would set positional parameters.  Since you've said:

```
IFS="."
```

before this, it'd imply that if the variable `A` was `123.42.10.42` then positional parameters `123`, `42`, `10`, `42` would be set which can be accessed using `$1`, `$2`, ...  (And, indeed, you could see those being utilized in setting other variables: `A1`, `A2`, ...)

---

Regarding the `${A1:-0}` notation, you could read about it in [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.